# convert a 2d tuple into a list

Tags: list, python-3.x, replace, tuples

i'm not very familiar with python, but i need to convert a 2d tuple into a nested list, i searched on stack i couldn't find an answer, Example:

```
Tuple = {(1,3),(3,5),(5,6)}
```

i need it to be a list:

```
List = [[1,3],[3,5],[5,6]]
```

why i need to convert a tuple, tuple wont allow me to use .replace on the content of the tuple

i tried to use`list()` as stated on the internet but it didn't convert the tuple, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this,

```
>>> Tuple = {(1,3),(3,5),(5,6)}
>>> [list(item) for item in Tuple]
[[5, 6], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

Or, you can use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

```
>>> list(map(list, Tuple))
[[5, 6], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function which performs better when you want to apply a built-in function on an iterable :

```
>>> Tuple = {(1,3),(3,5),(5,6)}
>>> list(map(list,Tuple))
[[5, 6], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

Comment: "since map returns the result as a list": only in older versions of Python, and the question is tagged 3-x.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
>>> Tuple = {(1,3),(3,5),(5,6)}
>>> [list(item) for item in Tuple]
[[5, 6], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```

or You can use [iterloops imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/future_builtins.html) for better performance

```
>>>import itertools
>>> Tuple = {(1,3),(3,5),(5,6)}
>>> list(itertools.imap(list, Tuple))
[[5, 6], [1, 3], [3, 5]]
```